# Angular 4 .Net Core project publish fails in VS 2017

Tags: angular, webpack, visual-studio-2017, .net-core-2.0

my project is developed angular 4 and .Net core 2.0 in VS 2017.
few NPM packages has also been installed to facilitate date time picker , RTE and popup. Also pipe to sanitize html.

I am unable to publish this solution , following errors thrown. running without errors, but publish fails.

```
The command "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod" exited with code 2

Can't resolve './../$$_gendir/ClientApp/app/app.module.browser.ngfactory' in 'C:\Projects\TestingProjects\DeploymentTesting\DeploymentTest2\DeploymentTest2\ClientApp'  DeploymentTest2 Module not found

an't resolve './../$$_gendir/ClientApp/app/app.module.server.ngfactory' in 'C:\Projects\TestingProjects\DeploymentTesting\DeploymentTest2\DeploymentTest2\ClientApp'    DeploymentTest2 Module not found
```

tried removing include:ClientApp from web pack, no luck

please share me a resolution for this.

Comment: Have you got the solution ?

Comment: No solution yet :(